# An automorphism of a function field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, automorphism-groups, function-fields

I am looking for an explicit example of a function field other than rational with an automorphism which fixes places of different degrees. Also, is there a counterexample, namely a function field with all the automorphisms don't fix any places of different degree.

Comment: Consider $\mathbb F_{13}(X)$ and in it places corresponding to irreducible polynomials $X^2+2,X^4+2$. They are both fixed by the automorphism induced by $X\mapsto -X$

Comment: Thank you but \mathbb F_{13}(X) is rational function field, I was looking for a different function field such as hyperelliptic

Comment: Ah apologies, I missed that part in the question.

Comment: Also a recommedation of a book or a thesis for begginers greatly appreciated. I couldnt find much information in Stichtenoth's Algebraic Function Fields and Codes about that question. I searched in web, but no luck. Algebraic Geometry's language can be hard to understand

Answer (score 2):

Take an elliptic curve with no rational 2-torsion points ($y^2=f(x)$) where $f(x)$ is a cubic that does not split over the base curve. Then the automorphism $P\to[−1]P$ fixes all the 2 torsion which has one rational point (of degree 1) and 3 non rational points corresponding to one rational point of degree 3.

To be very explicit: the function field could be the field of fractions of $\mathbb Q[x,y]/(y^2−(x^3+2))$ and the automorphism sends $y \to −y$.

This example will work in general for a hyperelliptic curve $y^2 = f(x)$ where $f(x)$ could be any squarefree polynomial of any degree. The 2 torsion corresponds to roots of $f(x)$ and $y \to -y$ is the involution. It's clear that you can get any combination of degrees for the fixed points if you let the genus grow.

Comment: Thank you very much Asvin, if you could suggest a book for begginners about these subjects or other materials, I would be grateful

Comment: Are you looking for anything in particular? If you just want to learn about curves Fulton's "Algebraic Curves" has a good reputation.

Comment: I would prefer a source presents the language of algebraic function fields, cause it is used generally in coding theory. Also, Stichtenoth's Algebraic Function Fields and Codes is a perfect source for it, but sometimes I just cant find what ı am looking for in it. Algebraic Curves is not my speciality, and its language can be a problem. But in my spare times I will look at it. I think I can fill the gaps with a good book. So, thank you

Comment: Maybe try this? https://books.google.com/books/about/Introduction_to_the_Theory_of_Algebraic.html?id=Ga5wAAAAQBAJ

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Asvin, I will look at them